# Count strpos match words

Tags: php, string, count, strpos

I want to find matching words from sentence using `strpos` my code is:

```
$a = 'hello my name is'; 
$b = 'hello my';    
if (strpos($a, $b) !== false) {
//here i want to display the number of matches words like count(strpos)
}
```

thanx

Comment: What does `strpos` have to do with counting? It just tells you the position of one string inside another.

Comment: http://us3.php.net/str_word_count ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, that strpos() deals with arguments as the whole strings and it can't recognize single word or spaces between words.

What you want to do is achievable only by using explode(" ", $string) on both strings, which gives you two arrays of words. Then iterate second array with foreach() and for every value check, if it does exist in the first array with in_array() function. You can add the variable that increases its value +1 every time in_array() is true.